# Debian Sid /etc/debian_version

Tags: debian

I have a question that I fear is already answered but the answer has thusfar successfully eluded me.

I installed Debian Wheezy via netinstall CD, changed sources to reflect Sid instead of Wheezy, did upgrade, reboot, dist-upgrade (should've done dist-upgrade from the start, I know), and rebooted again. When I cat /etc/debian_release, it still shows 7.0. Will that change or is it supposed to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Things placed in sid are targets for release via testing. You can think of it as a "staging" are for testing, which is currently Wheezy (7.0). The `/etc/debian_release` file will not change in sid until the base-files packages is updated in preparation for Jessie (8.0).

Since Debian is in a "freeze" to prepare the release, there won't be much difference between sid and Wheezy. Only bug fixes will be uploaded to sid until Wheezy has released.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Recently started using Debian after using Arch and CentOS (desktop and servers, respectively) and didn't know if that would change. Thanks again.